# c++ embedded SQL precompile with READ ONLY permission

Tags: c++, db2

Is it possible to

```
db2 connect somedb user myuser using mypwd  
db2 precompile myapp.sqx OUTPUT myapp.cxx
```

when I only have read permission to the REMOTE DB2 database?  I'm ONLY trying to select  I'm not trying to write to the database, yet the precompile command is complaining that I don't have permission to "create in"   ... What can I do differently such that I can query the database using c++  (I already have a ton of code I inherited that uses embedded sql precompiling, but the person who wrote it has write permission to the table, and I don't, so I'm hoping to adapt existing code somehow)

Comment: `PRECOMPILE` needs to create a package in the database that contains your embedded SQL, that's where the `CREATE IN` requirement is coming from. Unless you are willing to switch to dynamic SQL in your code, you cannot avoid creating the package(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `BINDFILE` option for the `PRECOMPILE` command if you do not have the ability to create packages in the database:

```
db2 "precompile myapp.sqx BINDFILE USING myapp.bnd OUTPUT myapp.cxx"
```

This will generate a file, `myapp.bnd` that you can use (or provide to your DBA) to create the package at a later date (along with the `myapp.cxx` file).

Please make sure that you track your bind files carefully with your precompiled code and binaries.  The bind files and generated source code are paired, so if you supply the wrong bind file with your binary you'll end up with version mismatch errors.

Comment: When I try that, the no access to "create in" error goes away, and is replaced with a no access to " " error...
SQL0551N "user" does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform operation " " on object "database.table.TEMPLATE.()". SQLSTATE=42501   

The only thing in my template.sqc file is a main function with "EXEC SQL CONNECT TO mydb user myuser using mypwd;"  and nothing else...

before i precompile, i db2 connect to the database, proving the username does have access to do what my app is trying to do.